# Add KML file as overlay to Google maps window

Tags: jquery, kml, google-maps-api-2

How do I add a KML file as an overlay when the code generating the Google Maps view is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#google_map_1').gMap({
        zoom:7,
        markers:[{
            address:'',
            latitude:51.486782,
            longitude:-0.143242,
            html:'London, United Kingdom',
            popup:true
        }],
        controls:[],
        maptype:G_NORMAL_MAP,
        scrollwheel:false

    });


});
```

Comment: I am not an experienced programmer so please point out if I forgot to mention some other important information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var road = new google.maps.KmlLayer( 
    'http://MUST-BE-A-WEBSITE.com/myfile.kml',
    {preserveViewport:true}
    );

road.setMap(map);
```

typically like that - watch out for that huge gotcha though - must be a website NOT a file served from localhost, somewhere that Google can parse, analyse and integrate it with their maptiles. Also, this example is gmaps v3 only. [Other stuff to watch out for](http://councilsites.posterous.com/upgrade-to-google-maps-v2-oily-rag-view) - including a list of KML gotchas.

Comment: Thank you. Since I cannot write JS, exactly where do I put these lines?

Comment: hilarious - this happened to be the first Q when I opened stack overflow today, and your answer solves a problem I was thinking about but hadn't dealt with yet :)

Comment: Ryley, where should I include the "road.setMap(map)"? Inside the jQuery? Also what if I use v2?

Comment: I would go and look in the documentation for Gmaps v2, thats where I found this sample for v3 - in the docs. You can change the var name from road to anything. It seems you are using jQuery plugin called gMap() - I'd check their docs and see if this is possible.

Comment: Sure thing, however as I am no JS programmer I would greatly appreciate it if somebody could give me more detailed instructions.

Comment: I am sorry, I will try and answer questions for nothing but not write code for you.  I am out.

Comment: Sorry if I upset you Cups, just that I know nothing about JS, and since this is the only piece of programming I need to do, it would be far more efficient if somebody experienced could help me out (as I think it would require just a few minutes of their time vs. several hours of mine). Still, thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem, I was not upset, just pointing out that there exists a line (for me) between the two - if it would only take a few minutes I would most likely have just posted the fix for you - and while I am a jQuery user, I don't use it to access Gmaps - never mind the fact that you have also a dependency on another jQuery plugin called gMap().  The best place to ask will be the owner of that plugin or the Google Maps v2 Google Group, which you can search for = that is where the really knowledgable Gmaps people are at.